# Nagios error with nrpe: install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't locate DBD/mysql.pm in @INC

Tags: centos, nagios, nrpe

I have configured Nagios on my Cent)S-6.5 machine and for some reason, when I open up Nagios web interface, I get these critical messages on some of my config:

```
CRITICAL - cannot connect to information_schema. 
install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't locate DBD/mysql.pm in @INC 
(@INC contains: /usr/local/nagios/libexec /usr/local/lib64/perl5 
/usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl 
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) 
at (eval 18) line 3.
```

I have all the perl files that nagios is complaining about and they are all readable. I have even installed nagios npre but still. It seems like a permission problem with the nrpe, but not sure how to resolve this so I can stop getting this **CRITICAL** error.

Any help to resolve the issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issues with the nagios-plugins package, Can you please check with following command and let me know which binary file are you using to check MySQL status.

```
rpm -q nagios-plugins-mysql
nagios-plugins-mysql-1.4.15-7.el6.x86_64

rpm -ql nagios-plugins-mysql
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_mysql
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_mysql_query
```

Answer (score 0):

The Nagios plugins package does include the MySQL driver.

If you are running mysqld on the server...

```
# yum list perl-DBD-mysql
```

...and see if it's installed.

```
# yum install perl-DBD-mysql
```

...to install it and any dependencies.

If you're not running mysqld...just remove the MySQL check command(s) from your Nagios configuration.

Comment: Hi MrCleanX. When i run the first command, it shows that the following package is installed: perl-DBD-MySQL.x86_64  4.013-3.el6    base

Comment: Run this to see what path it's installed in `perl -MDBD::mysql -le 'print $INC{"DBD/mysql.pm"}'`. On my CentOS7 box it's in /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl.